# I am trying to find out how IOSdriver and Iphondriver are related. Is one of them a newer version?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I guess one was used before Appium and the other is used now. But i am unable to find any documentatio to relate the two. Can somebody explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

IOSDriver is Appium's driver and can automate native apps, hybrid apps, and even Safari.
IPhoneDriver is Selenium's driver and can only automate Safari.

Sources:
https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/iphone/IPhoneDriver.html
http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/ios/IOSDriver.html